# How to cache model attributes in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my current configuration, a user's email is stored on a remote server that I need to hit with a curl quest.

Luckily, I only need the email once a day when a certain process runs. However, when that process does run it will need to reference the email multiple times.

This is the current accessor I have set up for `email`. The problem is the curl request is being called every time I use `$user->email`. What's the best way to avoid this?

**in UserModel:**

```
public function getEmailAttribute(){
    $curl = new Curl;
    $responseJson = $curl->post('https://www.dailycred.com/admin/api/user.json',array(
        'client_id'=>getenv('dailycredId')
        ,'client_secret'=>getenv('dailycredSecret')
        ,'user_id'=>$this->id
    ));
    $response = json_decode($responseJson);
    return $response->email;
}
```

Comment: Is that process in a single request (run) or on multiple requests? that is, do you need to store the value of email just for duration of single request or you want persistence like cache?

Comment: @VeljaMatic a single process. I don't need to persist. Maybe 'cache' was the wrong word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private $cached_email = false;

public function getEmailAttribute(){
  if ($this->cached_email){
    // if set return cached value
    return $this->cached_email;
  }
  // get the email
  $curl = new Curl;
  $responseJson = $curl->post('https://www.dailycred.com/admin/api/user.json',array(
    'client_id'=>getenv('dailycredId')
    ,'client_secret'=>getenv('dailycredSecret')
    ,'user_id'=>$this->id
  ));
  $response = json_decode($responseJson);
  // cache the value
  $this->cached_email = $response->email;
  // and return
  return $this->cached_email;
}
```

Depending on your use case make adjustments (ie. session, cache , static property...).

Comment: I guess this is the only way to do it, I assumed there would be some kind of standard implementation for this

Comment: Can we improve this code by adding a callback after the api call?

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 9 it is not a problem.

When yo making an attribute like this

```
public function label(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
                get: fn(): string => $this->name,
            )
            //->withoutObjectCaching()
            //->shouldCache()
            ;
}
```

you have option to add either `->withoutObjectCaching()` or `->shouldCache()`

**Important to note that the default behavior is almost unpredictable.**

I mean, it is actually predictable, but it depends on the type of an attribute.
The `objects` are cashed by default, the other types are not cashed by default.
*Personally I consider this sort of default behavior is very confusing and suggest to use explicitly either `->withoutObjectCaching()` or `->shouldCache()`*

Answer (score 1):

Extend a the Eloquent Model class

```
namespace App\Models\Utils;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as OldModel;

class MyModel extends OldModel
{
    private $cachedAttributes = [];

    public function getCachedAttribute(string $key, Callable $callable)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->cachedAttributes)) {
            $this->setCachedAttribute($key, call_user_func($callable));
        }

        return $this->cachedAttributes[$key];
    }


    public function setCachedAttribute(string $key, $value)
    {
        return $this->cachedAttributes[$key] = $value;
    }


    public function refresh()
    {
        unset($this->cachedAttributes);

        return parent::refresh();
    }
}
```

make your class

```
class ElementWithEmail extends MyModel
{
    const ATTRIBUTE_KEY_FOR_EMAIL = 'Email';

    public function getEmailAttribute(){
        $key = self::ATTRIBUTE_KEY_FOR_EMAIL;                    
        $callable = [$this, 'getEmail'];

       return $this->getCachedAttribute($key, $callable);
    }

    protected function getEmail()
    {
        $curl = new Curl;
        $responseJson = $curl->post('https://www.dailycred.com/admin/api/user.json',array(
            'client_id'=>getenv('dailycredId')
            ,'client_secret'=>getenv('dailycredSecret')
            ,'user_id'=>$this->id
        ));
        $response = json_decode($responseJson);

        return $response->email;
    }
}
```

Call it from your code

```
$element = new ElementWithEmail();
echo $element->email;
```